# how to put more control in each single cell of the editable gridview using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using grid view control in my web application..
My grid view is looking like this.

[image]

When clicking the Add button I am getting the result like this.. 
[image]

But my expected result is this one.. where is my mistake? what should I do?
[image]

This is my coding..

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {            
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("S.No", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Article No", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Item Description", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Order Quantity", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UOM", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Rate", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Currency", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Amount", typeof(string)));
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["S.No"] = 1;
        dr["Article No"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Item Description"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Order Quantity"] = 0;
        dr["UOM"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Rate"] = 0;
        dr["Currency"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Amount"] = 0;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        ViewState["currenttable"] = dt;
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();


        DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
        box2.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowSalesOrderArticleNumberInfo();
        box2.DataTextField = "Port_Number";
        box2.DataValueField = "Description";
        box2.DataBind();
        box2.Items.Insert(0, " ");

    DropDownList box12 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList3");
        box12.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowUnitItemInfo();
        box12.DataTextField = "Name";
        box12.DataValueField = "Symbol";
        box12.DataBind();
        box12.Items.Insert(0, " ");

        DropDownList box13 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList4");
        box13.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowUnitItemInfo();
        box13.DataTextField = "Name";
        box13.DataValueField = "Symbol";
        box13.DataBind();
        box13.Items.Insert(0, " ");

        DropDownList box14 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList5");
        box14.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowUnitItemInfo();
        box14.DataTextField = "Name";
        box14.DataValueField = "Symbol";
        box14.DataBind();
        box14.Items.Insert(0, " ");
       }

}
public void addnewrow()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;

    if (ViewState["currenttable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["currenttable"];
        DataRow drCurrentRow = null;



        for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("TextBox6");
            DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
            TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox8");
            TextBox box4 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox9");
            TextBox box5 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox10");
            TextBox box6 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox11");
            Label box7 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("Label6");
            TextBox box8 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox13");
            TextBox box9 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox14");
            TextBox box10 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox15");
            Label box11 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("Label7");
            DropDownList box12 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList3");
            DropDownList box13 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList4");
            DropDownList box14 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList5");
            Label box15 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("Label8");
            TextBox box16 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox17");
            TextBox box17 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox18");
            TextBox box18 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox19");
            Label box19 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("Label9");
            DropDownList box20 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("DropDownList7");
            DropDownList box21 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("DropDownList8");
            DropDownList box22 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("DropDownList9");
            Label box23 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("Label0");
            TextBox box24 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox21");
            TextBox box25 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox22");
            TextBox box26 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox23");

            drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
            drCurrentRow["S.No"] = i + 1;



            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Article No"] = box2.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Item Description"] = box3.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Item Description"] = box4.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Item Description"] = box5.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Item Description"] = box6.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Order Quantity"] = box8.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Order Quantity"] = box9.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Order Quantity"] = box10.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["UOM"] = box12.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["UOM"] = box13.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["UOM"] = box14.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Rate"] = box16.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Rate"] = box17.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Rate"] = box18.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Currency"] = box20.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Currency"] = box21.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Currency"] = box22.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Amount"] = box24.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Amount"] = box25.Text;
            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Amount"] = box26.Text;

            rowIndex++;
        }
        dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
        ViewState["currenttable"] = dtCurrentTable;

        GridView1.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
        GridView1.DataBind();


        for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
            box2.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowSalesOrderArticleNumberInfo();
            box2.DataTextField = "Port_Number";
            box2.DataValueField = "Description";
            box2.DataBind();
            box2.Items.Insert(0, " ");


        }



    }
    SetPreviousData();
}
private void SetPreviousData()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;
    if (ViewState["currenttable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["currenttable"];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBox box1 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("TextBox6");
                DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
                TextBox box3 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox8");
                TextBox box4 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox9");
                TextBox box5 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox10");
                TextBox box6 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("TextBox11");
                Label box7 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("Label6");
                TextBox box8 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox13");
                TextBox box9 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox14");
                TextBox box10 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("TextBox15");
                Label box11 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("Label7");
                DropDownList box12 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList3");
                DropDownList box13 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList4");
                DropDownList box14 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList5");
                Label box15 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("Label8");
                TextBox box16 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox17");
                TextBox box17 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox18");
                TextBox box18 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("TextBox19");
                Label box19 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("Label9");
                DropDownList box20 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("DropDownList7");
                DropDownList box21 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("DropDownList8");
                DropDownList box22 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("DropDownList9");
                Label box23 = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("Label0");
                TextBox box24 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox21");
                TextBox box25 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox22");
                TextBox box26 = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("TextBox23");


                box1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["S.No"].ToString();
                box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Article No"].ToString();
                box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Item Description"].ToString();
                box8.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Order Quantity"].ToString();
                box12.Text = dt.Rows[i]["UOM"].ToString();
                box16.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Rate"].ToString();
                box20.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Currency"].ToString();
                box24.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Amount"].ToString();

                rowIndex++;

            }
        }
    }
}


protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    addnewrow();

}
```

Comment: how can anyone tell without looking at your code ?

Comment: provide the codes.. we dont have a way to know what you are doing behind your add event

Comment: @Mathi you mean, your entered values goes blank when click on Add button... Right? and it is your problem... right?

Comment: yes..exactly @VishalPatel.

Comment: @Mathi One solution is like that : you need to store all things in session or any table variable and every postback you need to rebind your Grid by that session or table variable.

Comment: @Mathi Do you have use bindcontrol? If yes then Your table variable should contain columns for each and every gridview control value for bind control at every postback.

Comment: @Mathi Have you got the solution?

Comment: @Vishal Patel Now I added my coding in my question... just verify and give your solution.

Comment: @SurajSingh you are asking my coding right? I added my coding in my question itself.. give your solution

Comment: @Mathi I hope `Vishal Patel` answer solves your query .

Comment: @VishalPatel your answer was perfect.. I have one more problem... when I am clicking the Add Button the next row was displaying but the dropdownlist(Article No & UOM) was not loading data from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do below changes....

**1) In addnewrow() function change below code lines :**

```
dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Item Description"] = box3.Text;
dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Item Description"] = box4.Text;
dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Item Description"] = box5.Text;
dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Item Description"] = box6.Text;
```

change about code as below :

```
dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Item Description"] = box3.Text + "," + box4.Text + "," + box5.Text + "," + box6.Text;
```

And same logic apply to store value for Order Quantity, UOM, Rate, Currency and Amount fields/controls

**2) In SetPreviousData() function change below code line :**

```
box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Item Description"].ToString();
```

change about code as below :

```
if(Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Item Description"]).Trim() != "")
{
string[] strDesc = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["Item Description"]).Trim().Split(',');
box3.Text = strDesc[0].ToString();
box4.Text = strDesc[1].ToString();
box5.Text = strDesc[2].ToString();
box6.Text = strDesc[3].ToString();
}
```

And same logic apply to store value for Order Quantity, UOM, Rate, Currency and Amount fields/controls

Comment: your answer was perfect @VishalPatel.. I have one more problem... when I am clicking the Add Button the next row was displaying well but the dropdownlist(Article No & UOM) was not loading data from database. Give your solution.

Answer (score 0):

In addnewrow() function replace below code :

```
for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
            box2.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowSalesOrderArticleNumberInfo();
            box2.DataTextField = "Port_Number";
            box2.DataValueField = "Description";
            box2.DataBind();
            box2.Items.Insert(0, " ");


        }
```

Replace above code with below code lines...

```
for (int i = 0; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DropDownList box2 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList1");
            box2.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowSalesOrderArticleNumberInfo();
            box2.DataTextField = "Port_Number";
            box2.DataValueField = "Description";
            box2.DataBind();
            box2.Items.Insert(0, " ");

    DropDownList box12 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList3");
        box12.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowUnitItemInfo();
        box12.DataTextField = "Name";
        box12.DataValueField = "Symbol";
        box12.DataBind();
        box12.Items.Insert(0, " ");

        DropDownList box13 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList4");
        box13.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowUnitItemInfo();
        box13.DataTextField = "Name";
        box13.DataValueField = "Symbol";
        box13.DataBind();
        box13.Items.Insert(0, " ");

        DropDownList box14 = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("DropDownList5");
        box14.DataSource = SIMBL.ShowUnitItemInfo();
        box14.DataTextField = "Name";
        box14.DataValueField = "Symbol";
        box14.DataBind();
        box14.Items.Insert(0, " ");

}
```

Comment: No @VishalPatel.. I am getting something like "Index out of range Exception"..How to fix this exception.

Comment: @Mathi I have changed code "for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)"  
 with   "for (int i = 0; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)"   So please try again...

Comment: @VishalPatel..I have changed my code "for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count - 1; i++)" Now It's working fine..But the problem is 2nd  & next rows Amount(Quantity * Rate) output value was not working.. any solution.

Comment: @Mathi It's difficult to gather your requirement in comments. So could you please post it as a new question?

Comment: k @VishalPatel.. My requirement is not more.. Need to run my Grid View successfull based on this question.. when I am clicking the button  should work all the rows like a first row..my full coding is there in the question itself.  you got my requirement well.. so here  I am specially  asking from you..

Comment: @Mathi Could you please update your code... So I can easily fix your issue...?

Comment: @Mathi I have already explain for Amount textbox... follow earlier define steps "1) In addnewrow() function change below code lines :" and  "2) In SetPreviousData() function change below code line :"

Comment: @Mathi I have also commented in that answer like "And same logic apply to store value for Order Quantity, UOM, Rate, Currency and AMOUNT fields/controls"